# Fine Grained Cell Coloring with Excel and .NET

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Microsoft provides a .NET API to programatically set cell colors

```
Excel.Range rng2 = this.Application.get_Range("A1");
rng2.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
```

Is there a way to have two different colors within the [image]

Comment: Refer to the [Characters collection of the range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.characters(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do so for the color of the characters. You can't for the background. Background coloring can only be done on the whole cell

Here is a snippet (the definition of the XlColors enum is omitted)

```
        private static readonly Dictionary<string, XlColors> WordColoring = new Dictionary<string, XlColors>
                       {
                            {"linksaf", XlColors.Red},
                            {"schuin links", XlColors.Red},
                            {"links aanhouden", XlColors.Red},
                            {"rechtsaf", XlColors.Greenish},
                            {"schuin rechts", XlColors.Greenish},
                            {"rechts aanhouden", XlColors.Greenish},
                            {"rechtdoor", XlColors.Blue}
                       };

    public void TekstFormatter(Range cell)
    {
        string text = (cell.Value2 ?? "");

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, XlColors> colorPair in WordColoring)
        {
            int pos = text.IndexOf(colorPair.Key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            if (pos != -1)
            {
                Characters chars = cell.Characters[pos + 1, colorPair.Key.Length];
                chars.Font.Color = colorPair.Value;
                chars.Font.Bold = true;
            }                
        }
    }
```